# sorting version numbers stored as string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting

Say I have an array like this:

```
let arr = ["1.2.5", "1", "10", "2.0.4", "3.3.3.3"];
```

What would be the best way to sort this and get result like this:

```
let arr = ["1", "1.2.5", "2.0.4", "3.3.3.3", "10"];
```

First I thought of converting each item in the array into 'float' may work but then multiple decimals won't give expected results.

I can also go for a `for` loop and doing stuff like `item.split(".")` and then check one by one, but I do not think this is the best way.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: is 3.3.3.3 a number? no right?

Comment: yeah i know but what i don't know what else i call it to explain what result i expect. However i do hope you get my point here.

Comment: 2.0.4 is not a number just like others, and hence it can't be sorted like numericals.

Comment: ok, what i want is not 'sort like numbers' but just sorting. Please let me know if i can rewrite my question in a better for explanation.

Comment: You can try sorting by first number. `arr.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.split('.')[0] - b.split('.')[0];
    });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function compare(a, b) {
    var aSplit = a.split(".");
    var bSplit = b.split(".");


    var length = Math.min(aSplit.length, bSplit.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (parseInt(aSplit[i]) < parseInt(bSplit[i])) {
            return -1;
        } else if (parseInt(aSplit[i]) > parseInt(bSplit[i])) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (aSplit.length < bSplit.length) {
        return -1;
    } else if (aSplit.length > bSplit.length) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can use it like: arr.sort((a, b) => compare(a, b));

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `options`

> **sensitivity**
>
> Which differences in the strings should lead to non-zero result values. Possible values are:
>
> - `"base"`: Only strings that differ in base letters compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a = A`.
> - `"accent"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or accents and other diacritic marks compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a = A`.
> - `"case"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or case compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a ≠ A`.
> - `"variant"`: Strings that differ in base letters, accents and other diacritic marks, or case compare as unequal. Other differences may also be taken into consideration. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a ≠ A`.
>
> The default is "variant" for usage "sort"; it's locale dependent for usage "search".
>
> **numeric**
>
> Whether numeric collation should be used, such that "1" < "2" < "10". Possible values are `true` and `false`; the default is `false`. This option can be set through an options property or through a Unicode extension key; if both are provided, the `options` property takes precedence. Implementations are not required to support this property.

```js
var array = ["1.2.5", "1", "10", "2.0.4", "3.3.3.3"];

array.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (uses ES6 syntax)

```js
const arr = ["1.2.5", "1", "10", "2.0.4", "3.3.3.3"];

const result = arr
.map((n) => n.split('.').map((c) => c.padStart(10, '0')).join('.'))
.sort()
.map((n) => n.split('.').map((c) => +c).join('.'))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you please explain this a little bit

Comment: the 1st map() adds leading zeros, i.e it does the following conversion "1.2.3" => "0000000001.0000000002.0000000003" and after that sorting works correctly. The 2nd map() just removes leading zeros.

Comment: well that's a nice way to do it, thanks for explaining. I didn't knew about padStart

Answer (score 0):

var arr = ["1.2.5", "1", "10", "2.0.4", "3.3.3.3"];

```js
var arr = ["1.2.5", "1", "10", "2.0.4", "3.3.3.3"];
console.log(arr.sort(function(a,b){

  var arr1 = a.split('.');
  var arr2 = b.split('.');
  
  var maxlen = Math.max(arr1.length,arr2.length);
  
  var i;

  for(i = 0;i<maxlen;i++){
    var i1 = parseInt(arr1[i] || 0)
      var i2 = parseInt(arr2[i] || 0)
   if(i1 < i2){
         return -1;
      }
      else if(i1 > i2){
         return 1;
      }
  }
  
  return 0;

}));
```

Answer (score -1):

- sort `1.0a` notation correct
- use native `localeCompare` to sort `1.090` notation

```js
function log(label,val){
  document.body.append(label,String(val).replace(/,/g," - "),document.createElement("BR"));
}

const sortVersions = (
  x,
  v = s => s.match(/[a-z]|\d+/g).map(c => c==~~c ? String.fromCharCode(97 + c) : c)
) => x.sort((a, b) => (a + b).match(/[a-z]/) 
                             ? v(b) < v(a) ? 1 : -1 
                             : a.localeCompare(b, 0, {numeric: true}))

let v=["1.90.1","1.090","1.0a","1.0.1","1.0.0a","1.0.0b","1.0.0.1","1.0a"];
log(' input : ',v);
log('sorted: ',sortVersions(v));
log('no dups:',[...new Set(sortVersions(v))]);
```